# How to mock UUID in Spock + PowerMock?

Tags: uuid, spock, powermock

If I want to mock a static method, I need to use PowerMock.
I tested well in PowerMock + JUnit, but failed in combination with Spock.

**Encry.java**

```java
public class Encrypt {
    public String genUUID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

**EncryptTest2Java.java** works:

```java
@PrepareForTest({ UUID.class, Encrypt.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class EncryptTest2Java {
    @Test
    public void genUUID() {
        final String id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f";
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UUID.class);
        PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid);
        Encrypt encrypt = new Encrypt();
        Assert.assertEquals(id, encrypt.genUUID());
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work in Spock:

**EncryptTest.groovy**

```groovy
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik.class)
@PrepareForTest([UUID.class, Encrypt.class])
class EncryptTest extends Specification {
    def "PasswordGenerator"() {
        given:
        final String id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f";
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id)

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UUID.class)
        PowerMockito.when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid)
        Encrypt encrypt = new Encrypt()

        when:
        String ret = encrypt.genUUID()

        then:
        ret == id
    }
}
```

**Error information:**

```
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST
Notifications are not supported when all test-instances are created first!
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST
Notifications are not supported for behaviour ALL_TESTINSTANCES_ARE_CREATED_FIRST

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.


    at arthur.dy.lee.mybatisplusdemo.EncryptTest.PasswordGenerator(EncryptTest.groovy:24)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

What should I do? Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: You already (partially) did the right thing: You wrapped the static method call into a non-static method. Why don't you just mock that one without PowerMock? Using PM is a smell IMO. It smells like you should refactor your code instead of using dirty mocking tricks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this one again and reproduced it on my machine. I created [Spock ticket #1014](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1014) in order to ask for an explanation and a workaround.

Meanwhile I found a workaround via `PowerMockito.stub`, at least for the simple case in which you don't want to check any interactions (i.e. verify how many times a method with specific parameters is called):

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q55101703

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import spock.lang.Specification

import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.stub

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik)
@PrepareForTest(Encrypt)
class EncryptTest extends Specification {

  def testUUID() {
    given:
    def id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f"
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id)
    stub(method(UUID, "randomUUID")).toReturn(uuid)

    expect:
    new Encrypt().genUUID() == id
  }

}
```

---

**Update:** Actually there is a way to work around this and use both `when-theReturn` and `verifyStatic`, either with your own static classes or with system classes.

Furthermore, this is not a Spock issue but a Groovy issue as it also happens with JUnit tests written in Groovy. The workaround is to use `@CompileStatic` for Groovy JUnit tests. In Spock you cannot use static compilation for feature methods or whole specifications, as Spock depends on Grrovy's dynamic features. But you can use helper methods doing the PowerMock stuff and annotate those with `@CompileStatic`.

I have documented my findings in [PowerMock ticket #1008](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1008#issuecomment-536166868)
I have documented my findings. There you will also find sample code. In your case the solution looks like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q55101703

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import spock.lang.Specification

import static de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q55101703.EncryptTest.PowerMockHelper.*
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik)
@PrepareForTest([Encrypt, UUID])
class EncryptTest extends Specification {

  def testUUID() {
    given:
    def id = "493410b3-dd0b-4b78-97bf-289f50f6e74f"
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(id)
    testUUID_mockStatic(uuid)

    expect:
    new Encrypt().genUUID() == id
    // This does not work because UUID is final. Otherwise it would work.
    //PowerMockHelper.testUUID_verifyStatic()
  }

  @CompileStatic
  static class PowerMockHelper {
    def static testUUID_mockStatic(UUID uuid) {
      mockStatic(UUID)
      when(UUID.randomUUID()).thenReturn(uuid)
    }

    def static testUUID_verifyStatic() {
      // This does not work for final classes, at least not with Mockito back-end.
      // Maybe there is a way with EasyMock. The documentation at least mentions
      // mocking final classes for EasyMock, but I only saw an example with non-static
      // methods.
      //
      // Executing the following line yields this error:
      // org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
      //   Cannot mock/spy class java.util.UUID
      //   Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
      //     - final class
      verifyStatic(UUID, times(1))
      UUID.randomUUID()
      true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are good news for you: I found a workaround. See my updated answer. Feel free to ask if you do not understand.